# Sklearn list of algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

Is there anywhere a list or directory which matches an algorithm or class of algorithm to a task for which this algorithm is appropriate? Like on the homepage of [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

For example:
Text classification  --> Naive Bayes
Prediction of continuous labels --> LinearRegression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not exactly a list, but [sklearn website](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) does provide the following flowchart, which gives suggestions regarding which algorithms to use, based on your task and the quantity of data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also I have found in the [sklearn 0.11](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/tutorial/text_analytics/general_concepts.html) documentation a list which describes the fields of application of different algorithms.

***....***

[image]

***....***

Further the chapter [How to select the right algorithm for the task](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/tutorial/text_analytics/which_algorithm.html) gives a hint wich algorithm could be appropriate.